# Using a 7.1 Soundcard to realize multiple outputs

Tags: c#, output, naudio, soundcard

I am wondering if it´s possible to use my 7.1-Soundcard as an at least 4 to 6 Channel output.
My destination is to play a file on the front speakers and another file to the rear speakers. So I can mix them using an analog mixer and finally returning them to a line-in so that the result can be recorded or streamed.
Is this basically possible is this a misunderstanding of the possabilities of my soundcard?

In Naudio the usb-Device just shows up as a 2-Channel USB-Headset even if it is set up da a 7.1-Device in Windows.

Can anybody explain my fault and give me a hint how to realize this using Softwaretools or .Net-Programming (preferred in c#) ??

Greetings from Northern Germany

Martin

Comment: I would take a look at FFMPEG, there you can create audio streams / files. Eg: AC3, MP3, AAC. But i doubt this can be solved with a simple stack overflow answer, you will have to write lots of code for this, or try to use some audio mixer software.

Comment: DirectX 9.0c used to have a 5.1 API. But it got thrown on the scrap heap when MS moved to DirectX 10. Too bad because it worked really well.